# Grab all characters inside {...} if not contain "{" and "}"

Tags: php, regex, pcre, regex-negation

I want catch all character inside `{ ... }`,

If inside not found "`{`" and "`}`"

So for example:

```
{amdnia91(\+wowa}
```

Catch it.

```
{amdn{ia91(\+wowa}
```

Not catch (contain "`{`").

```
preg_match_all('#(.+?)\{(.+?)\}#', $input, $output);
```

How fix it?

EDIT.
Explained more:

I will try to create css minifier.
But there i need catch all names and content inside brackets as separate array value.

Curret $input look like this:

```
.something{property:value;prop2:value}#something2{someprop:val;prop:val}
```

It is also minfied so containt multiple ...{}...{} inline.
And my code catch all good but...
This catch also if inside brackets its brackets,
but i don't want catch it if contain brackets inside.

Comment: Do you mean you do not want to match at all if there is a `{` inside `{...}`? Not even a part of it?

Comment: I want match only if inside {...} not found { and }, otherwise match.

Comment: Let me clarify: is [that](https://regex101.com/r/wT2jZ2/1) OK? daiscog's answer is almost the same.

Comment: Yes,  thats will be ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^}{]` means match any character that is not } or {.

So:

```
preg_match_all('#\{([^}{]+)\}#', $input, $output);
```

However, note that in your `{amdn{ia91(+wowa}` example, this *will* match the `ia91(+wowa` fragment.

**EDIT**

If you didn't want any match at all for that second example, then try this:

```
preg_match_all('#^[^}{]*\{([^}{]+)\}[^}{]*$#', $input, $output);
```

The regex broken down means:

- `^` - The start of the line
- `[^}{]*` - Any character which is not { or } zero or more times
- `\{` - The literal { character
- `([^}{]+)` - Capture one or more characters which are not { or }
- `\}` - The literal } character
- `[^}{]*` - Any character which is not { or } zero or more times
- `$` - The end of the line

[Demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/nG0nS4/1)

**Second Edit**

Given your further explanation on what you need, I'd suggest this:

```
preg_match_all('#(?<=^|})[^}{]*?\{([^}{]+?)\}(?=[^}]*$|[^}]*\{)#', $input, $output);
```

This uses a "look-behind" and a "look-ahead".  Broken down, it means:

- `(?<=^|})` Lookbehind:  Assert that this is either the start of the line or that the previous character was a literal '}' *but do not include that character as part of the whole match*
- `[^}{]*?` - Lazily match zero or more characters which are not { or }
- `\{` - A literal {
- `([^}{]+?)` - Lazily capture one or more characters which are not { or }
- `\}` - A literal }
- `(?=[^}]*$|[^}]*\{)` - Lookahead:  Ensure that the following characters are either zero or more characters which are not } followed by the line end, or zero or more characters which are not } followed by a literal { *but do not include those characters as part of the whole match*

[Demonstration](https://regex101.com/r/nG0nS4/4)

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oK9xT4/1 - no idea if this is expected. Actually, there is no point in lazy quantifier, it works the same way as a greedy one here.

Comment: True.  I shall remove it.

Comment: @daiscog. But i want get $output only if inside brackets not found other brackets.

Comment: @KsaR Yes, as my answer says, that's what `[^}{]+` means - it means match 1 or more characters which *are not* { or }.

Comment: But this must not match content if brackets inside brackets... Not other charcter. So if inside brackets found brackets, must not catch it (your code catch).. But if not found brackets inside then catch full content.

Comment: Thank you for second edit, in 70% its that what i need. But,  receive in $output two arrays [0] that contain in values something like .x{yy}, (thats ok) [1] that contain content that is inside bracket (also ok)...But don't receive [2]: only names (all before "{" bracket like .className etc).. maybe you have any solution ?

Comment: Try adding capturing brackets around the first `[^}{]*?` in the regex to capture everything before the first `{`

Answer (score 2):

I am posting an alternative to the regex posted by daiscog based on the concept of matching what we do not need and omitting it, and only match what we need later with the help of PCRE `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs:

```
[#.]?[^{}]*{[^{}]*[{}][^{}]*}(*SKIP)(*F)|[#.]?[^{}]*{([^{}]+)}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zH1mU5/1)

**What does it match?**

- `[#.]?[^{}]*{[^{}]*[{}][^{}]*}(*SKIP)(*F)` - an optional `.` or `#` (see `[#.]?`) followed with 0+ characters other than `{` and `}` (see `[^{}]*`) followed with a `{`, that is again followed with `[^{}]*`, followed with either `{` or `}` (see `[{}]`) and then again `[^{}]*` and a closing `}`. This part matches strings like `.something{` or nothing. Then, once matched, discard this match from the matches returned due to the `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs.
- `|` - or...
- `[#.]?[^{}]*{([^{}]+)}` -  an optional `.` or `#` (see `[#.]?`) followed with 0+ characters other than `{` and `}` (see `[^{}]*`), then `{`, then 1+ characters other than braces (`[^{}]+`) and a closing brace `}`. This is what we will keep and get as matches.

[PHP demo](http://ideone.com/sn8zJy):

```
$re = '~[#.]?[^{}]*{[^{}]*[{}][^{}]*}(*SKIP)(*F)|[#.]?[^{}]*{([^{}]+)}~'; 
$str = "{amdnia91(+wowa}\n{amdn{ia91(+wowa}\n.something{property:value;prop2:value}#something2{someprop:val;prop:val}\n.something{property:value{;prop2:value}#something2{someprop:val;prop:val}\n.something{property:v}alue;prop2:value}#something2{someprop:val;prop:val}"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {amdnia91(+wowa}
            [1] => 
.something{property:value;prop2:value}
            [2] => #something2{someprop:val;prop:val}
            [3] => #something2{someprop:val;prop:val}
            [4] => #something2{someprop:val;prop:val}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => amdnia91(+wowa
            [1] => property:value;prop2:value
            [2] => someprop:val;prop:val
            [3] => someprop:val;prop:val
            [4] => someprop:val;prop:val
        )

)
```

Comment: I undeleted my answer since [you confirm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36691046/grab-all-characters-inside-if-not-contain-and/36691098#comment60970884_36691046) that you want to match `ia91(+wowa` inside `{amdn{ia91(+wowa}`. Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wT2jZ2/1) of my regex.

Comment: You would need the lazy quantifier here, else `{abc}def}` would match `abc}def` in the capturing group